# Hibernate hangs abruptly at cfg.buildSessionFactory()

Tags: java, hibernate

I have started to learn Hibernate and was following some tutorial.
While trying out one of the examples, I am not able to proceed further and not able to see or understand what is exactly happening....

Here is my code....(I have a normal cfg file)
My class are as follows:

UserDetails.java:

```
 package pack.dto;

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "user_details")

 public class UserDetails {
    @Id
    private int userId;
    private String userName;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date joinedDate;
    @Embedded
    private Address address;
    @Lob
    private String description;
    public Integer age;

    public int getUserId() {
       return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
       this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
       return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
       this.userName = userName;
    }

    public Date getJoinedDate() {
       return joinedDate;
    }

    public void setJoinedDate(Date joinedDate) {
       this.joinedDate = joinedDate;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
       return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
       this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
       return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
       this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "UserDetails [userId=" + userId + ", userName=" + userName
            + ", joinedDate=" + joinedDate + ", address=" + address
            + ", description=" + description + ", age=" + age + "]";
}
```

}

And my Address.java class is as follows which I am trying to embed with the UserDetails class:

```
 package pack.dto;
 import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

 @Embeddable
 public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String pinCode;

    public String getStreet() {
       return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
       this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
       return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
       this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
       return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
       this.state = state;
    }

    public String getPinCode() {
       return pinCode;
    }

    public void setPinCode(String pinCode) {
       this.pinCode = pinCode;
    }


 }
```

And some Important tags from my cfg file are as follows:

```
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatedb</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>

 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
 <!--I have mapped only the userdetails class as Address class is to be embedded -->
<mapping class="pack.dto.UserDetails"/>
```

And I am testing it with the following code:

```
    UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("Neeraj");
    user.setDescription("Great Coder");
    user.setJoinedDate(new Date());
    user.age = 24;

    Address addrNeeraj = new Address();
    addrNeeraj.setCity("Pune");
    addrNeeraj.setPinCode("411004");
    addrNeeraj.setState("Maharashtra");
    addrNeeraj.setStreet("KarveRoad");
    user.setAddress(addrNeeraj);

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.clear();
    session.close();
    session.getSessionFactory().close();
    sessionFactory.close();
```

When I tried to debug this code, the code got stuck at :

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
            .buildSessionFactory();
```

and the SessionFactory was never created.
And the logs were got stuck at:

```
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:20 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
  INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.6.Final}
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
  INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment      buildBytecodeProvider
  INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:22 AM       org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
  INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:22 AM   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
  WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:22 AM   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
  INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatedb]
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
  INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
  INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:22 AM  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
  INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:23 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
  INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  Jan 03, 2016 8:02:24 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
  INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
  Hibernate: drop table if exists user_details
```

The logs did not proceed further `Hibernate: drop table if exists user_details`. Why is this happening? What is wrong in my code? Why is SessionFactory not being created?

Answer (score 1):

(1)While building sessionFactory , hibernate tries to read file name hibernate.cfg.xml ,

So your cfg file name must be same as this.

below can be your cfg file :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="pack.dto.UserDetails" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

(2)Try to use this code for creating sessionFactory , (works for hibernate version 4.3.x)

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    /**
     * One connection from a DB requires only one instance of sessionFactory in
     * an application.
     * 
     * @return SessionFactory
     */
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .buildServiceRegistry();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Below code saving UserDetails

```
UserDetails user = new UserDetails();
user.setUserId(1);
user.setUserName("Neeraj");
user.setDescription("Great Coder");
user.setJoinedDate(new Date());
user.age = 24;

Address addrNeeraj = new Address();
addrNeeraj.setCity("Pune");
addrNeeraj.setPinCode("411004");
addrNeeraj.setState("Maharashtra");
addrNeeraj.setStreet("KarveRoad");
user.setAddress(addrNeeraj);

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

U must put the port on the configuration to create a sessionFactory

```
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<!-- port 3306 or whatever u use -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue.. In my case restarting mysql service worked..

```
sudo service mysql restart
```